# why netty can not continuously send message?

Tags: java, netty, nio

I wrote a server to send  large number of message to  all clients  after connecting.

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    while (true){
       content = arrayblockqueue.poll()
       ctx.writeAndFlush(content+"\r\n");
    }
}
```

after sending thousands of message , the channel do not send message anymore. through debugging, I found that AbstractNioByteChannel.incompleteWrite was  invoked and the selectionKey will be add  SelectionKey.OP_WRITE when the network is congestion. After being set OP_WRITE , AbstractNioUnsafe.isFlushPending() will  return true so the flush() can not be done indeed .  How to let netty recover this situation ? Or I use netty in a wrong way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handler method is invoked directly from an I/O thread.  Until your handler method returns, the I/O thread which called the handler method cannot perform any I/O, and that's why you are not seeing anything is written.

Looking from your code, what you want is to get a message from a blocking queue and write it to a channel.  Instead of using a blocking queue, you can just write to the channel.  Almost all operations in Netty are thread safe.  For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ...
    Channel ch = ...;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {
        ch.writeAndFlush(String.valueOf(i) + "\r\n");
    }
    ...
}

// And your handler doesn't need an arrayblockingqueue.
```

However, the code above will probably make the event queue of Netty grow infinitely, resulting `OutOfMemoryError`.  To prevent the write requests from being queued infinitely, you have to use the future returned by the `writeAndFlush()` operation.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {
    ChannelFuture f = ch.writeAndFlush(String.valueOf(i) + "\r\n");
    if ((i + 1) % 100 == 0) {
        // Wait until the write request is actually finished
        // so that the event queue becomes empty.
        f.sync();  
    }
}
```